# Are Grails Plugin service integration tests with GORM supposed to work?

Tags: grails, testing, integration-testing, grails-plugin

## Update

@Ramsharan's answer below is correct. This is arguably a defect in Grails itself, but certainly a documentation problem. I added a defect report to the Grails Jira https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11595. I also added the test code (including fix) to GitHub: https://github.com/xnickmx/grails-2.4.2-plugin-integration-test-example

---

## Original Question:

Note: this exact series of steps work if I create an app instead of a plugin.

## Overview

My Grails plugin project has a service method that attempts to create a domain class. Calling the service's method from an integration test results in a

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [Domain class] was used outside of a Grails application.

## Background

1. Grails version 2.4.2 running on Windows 7
2. Start from scratch with a **Plugin** project (example: GrailsTestPlugin)
3. Create a simple domain class (example: Person)
4. Create a simple service class (example: PersonService) with a method that creates domain class instances (example: createPerson)
5. Create an integration test that calls the service class method (example: PersonServiceITSpec)
6. Run the tests and get a NullPointerException. Symptoms very similar to [GRAILS-10538](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/1501) (but this bug mentions unit tests and is supposededly fixed). It fails this way in both Application and Plugin projects.
7. Change the service's @Transactional annotation to static transactional = true and run the tests again. This time the tests fail with

   > java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [org.grails.testplugin.domain.Person] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
   >       at org.grails.testplugin.service.PersonService.createPerson(PersonService.groovy:13)

If I change my service class to no longer attempt to create a domain class instance, it works.

## What's happening?

This seems like basic Grails functionality. I'm surprised it doesn't seem to work in plugin projects. Am I doing something wrong? Is this not supposed to work? Is it a bug?

## Details

org.grails.testplugin.domain.Person.groovy:

```
package org.grails.testplugin.domain

class Person {

    String name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

org.grails.testplugin.service.PersonService:

```
package org.grails.testplugin.service

import grails.transaction.Transactional
import org.grails.testplugin.domain.Person

//@Transactional have to comment out to avoid NPE
class PersonService {

    static transactional = true

    Person createPerson(String name) {

    new Person(name: name).save()
    }
}
```

Create integration test:

> create-integration-test org.grails.testplugin.service.PersonServiceITSpec

contents:

```
package org.grails.testplugin.service

import spock.lang.*

import static org.junit.Assert.*

/**
 * Tests PersonService
 */
class PersonServiceITSpec extends Specification {

    private PersonService personService

    def setup() {
        personService = new PersonService()
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test createPerson happy path"() {
        given:
        final name = "name"

        when:
        final result = personService.createPerson(name)

        then:
        assertNotNull(result)
        assertEquals(name, result.name)
        assertNotNull(result.getId())
    }
}
```

Run the tests

> grails test-app integration:

Comment: What happens if you use dependency injection instead of manually creating the `PersonService`?

Comment: Integration test should inherit `IntegrationSpec` instead of `Specification`.

Comment: @SérgioMichels I'm not sure I follow. Where should I use dependency injection? Which code should be changed?

Comment: @dmahapatro using IntegrationSpec makes no difference. It fails with the same exception. "grails create-integration-test" created this class and made it extend Specification instead of IntegrationSpec, so my hunch is that part is ok. In addition, according to this thread, http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-2-3-Integration-tests-with-Spock-td4654230.html, the test compiler and AST transformations ensure that integration tests get everything they need automatically.

Comment: @xnickmx exactly the Ramsharan's answer is what I wanted to say hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are running integration test, you do not need to do `new` for service. Your test should be something like this

```
import spock.lang.*

class PersonServiceITSpec extends Specification {

    PersonService personService
    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test createPerson happy path"() {
        given:
        final String name = 'name'

        when:
        def result = personService.createPerson(name)

        then:
        result != null
        name == result.name
        result.id != null
    }
}
```

The framework will automatically inject personService in the field and it should not be private.

Instead of extending `Specification` class, I would prefer extending `IntegrationSpec`.

**UPDATE:**

The reason for the error is the missing of hibernate plugin. **When we create new plugin, hibernate plugin is not added in plugin dependency**. So the test which contains domain will create problem. So add

`runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.16"`

in BuildConfig.groovy in plugins dependency. It may look like this

`plugins {
        build(":release:3.0.1",
              ":rest-client-builder:1.0.3") {
            export = false
        }
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.16"
    }`

It may be better to change the scope of hibernate to test.

Comment: Yes I have tried myself and there is no problem with this code. I have created simple project with above test. You can look on this and pull  it and run the test. And I am using grails 2.4.1 version.

Comment: I have also checked in grails 2.4.2 and it's working.

Comment: Weird...it's still failing for me. Failure:  |
test createPerson happy path(org.grails.testplugin.service.PersonServiceITSpec)
 |
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [org.grails.testplugin.domain.Person] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a
test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly....createPerson happy path(PersonServiceITSpec.groovy:26)
|Completed 1 integration test, 1 failed in 0m 1s
.Tests FAILED

Comment: I have created simple project https://github.com/ramsharan065/serviceIntegrationTest. Can you just pull it and run the test?

Comment: I am able to replicate the above error `Failure:  test createPerson happy path(org.test.PersonServiceITSpec)| java.lang.IllegalStateException: Method on class [org.test.Person] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
 at org.test.PersonService$$EOkNecCm.$tt__createPerson(PersonService.groovy:10) at org.test.PersonServiceITSpec.test createPerson happy path(PersonServiceIT..)|Completed 1 integration test, 1 failed in 0m 0s` in the above test project when import of Person domain is wrong in PersonService.

Comment: So can you recheck the import of domain Person in PersonService. 

In above test project, if I replace
`import org.test.domain.Person` with `import org.test.Person` in PersonService then I will get the above error message. So it can be the possible reason for the error.

Comment: The hibernate plugin fixed it. Thanks! This was not obvious to me at all. I haven't found any docs that mention this. I will see if I can file a defect on the Grails docs to remedy this.

Comment: In http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#creatingAndInstallingPlugins, it has noted that `The only plugins included in a new plugin project are Tomcat and Release. Hibernate is not included by default.`

Comment: I have EXACTLY the same issue, and, sadly it is not solved by adding the runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" line.  I had hibernate imported.